# How to apply the bcrypt on my php

Tags: php

DBOperations.php

```
public function userLogin($username, $pass){
    $password = $pass;
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT s_id FROM students WHERE s_id = ? AND password = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $password);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result(); 
    return $stmt->num_rows > 0; 
}
```

userLogin.php

```
<?php 

require_once '../include/DbOperations.php';

$response = array(); 

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    if(isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])){
        $db = new DbOperations(); 

        if($db->userLogin($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])){
            $user = $db->getUserByUsername($_POST['username']);
            $response['error'] = false; 
            $response['id'] = $user['id'];
            $response['firstname'] = $user['firstname'];
            $response['lastname'] = $user['lastname'];
            $response['middlename'] = $user['middlename'];
            $response['s_id'] = $user['s_id'];
        }else{
            $response['error'] = true; 
            $response['message'] = "Invalid username or password";          
        }

    }else{
        $response['error'] = true; 
        $response['message'] = "Required fields are missing";
    }
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

I already try the "password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT)" still it doesn't work.
I search and I try them apply on it but still it doesn't work

Comment: WARNING: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern development framework like Laravel comes with a robust authentication system built-in. 

With that being said,  have you tried  password_hash("Your Password", PASSWORD_DEFAULT) and then to verify it have you tried password_verify("Your Plain Text Password", "Your Hashed Password From The Database")

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you're storing the hash from [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) in the database.

Select the password for the username, then check it with [password_verify()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php).

```
<?php
public function userLogin($username, $pass) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT password FROM students WHERE s_id = ? LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    if ($result->num_rows === 0) {
       return false; 
    }

    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    return password_verify($pass, $row['password']);
}
```

Comment: As I said in the comments section after my warning LOL.

Comment: What do you mean? I posted my answer abit under 2 mins *before* your comment. Also It took me 5mins to look up mysqli api  (as not used it in years). and write the answer.

Comment: Oh I’m sorry I had been typing that out for about 5 minutes and after I hit submit and refreshed I seen this. I wasn’t trying to imply that you took my comment or anything but more like I am agreeing that this is the correct answer. Matter of fact I upvoted it after I said that lol